# jQuery AJAX post to PHP everytime a click is fired off

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I want to keep a record of every click that occurs within a specific `DIV` and child `DIVS` on page. The client should not be aware of this. Inside of the `div` is a link to an external website.

Client clicks link inside `div` > ajax inserts record in db > client is sent to site of link clicked

**PHP on page**

```
include('quotemaster/dbmodel.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['dataString'])) {
    clickCounter();
}
```

**PHP Model Function**

```
function clickCounter() {
    global $host, $user, $pass, $dbname;
        try {
            $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
            $stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO clickcounter (counter) VALUES (1)");
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

}
```

**AJAX POST**

```
$(function() {
    $("body").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "results" || $(e.target).parents("#results").size()) { 
            //alert("Inside div");
            ajax_post();
        } 
    });
})

function ajax_post() {
    var dataString = 'CC='+1;  
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "tq/--record-events.inc.php",  data: dataString }); 
}
```

The problem I am having (I think) is that the `AJAX` post is not being sent. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is your alert("Inside div") triggered?

Comment: Yes it is. That works. It's just not sending the POST. I know the model works too because if I `!isset` a record is created in the `DB`

Comment: try `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "tq/--record-events.inc.php",  data: {dataString : dataString} }); `

Comment: @Dheed Does not work.

Comment: can you try to print/dump the $_POST array? `var_dump` or `file_put_content('array', print_r($_POST,true));`

Comment: @BrendanBullen  Do you think this questions warrants a down vote? I don't. It's perfectly sensible. Can you help?

Comment: @in-spired No, I don't think the question warrants a down-vote. The value of the question to the community remains to be seen which is why I haven't up-voted it (it may be a problem specific to your code as opposed to a potential learning opportunity for others) but whomever down-voted it should give it further consideration. As far as help goes, I'm having a look.

Comment: @in-spired When you uncomment the alert does it show?

Comment: Yes it does show. Everything seems to work. Except for the AJAX post.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the DIV?

Comment: `<div id="results" style="background-color:#333;"> ...  </div>`

Comment: @Dheed Its just `CC=1`

Comment: @in-spired is $_POST an array ? I would like to know the structure of $_POST, have you tried to check if isset $_POST[0]?

Comment: No, `$_POST` is just the dataString `var`

Comment: @in-spired because $_POST is an associative array and with ajax you only pass a string, not a key : value object

Comment: Also I have taken a look around the web and pass the data in your way is wrong: use an object

Comment: @Dheed I am researching your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

on your PHP you have

```
if(isset($_POST['dataString'])) {...
```

you are expecting a parameter named dataString so you can fix it on your javascript ajax_post function with something like

```
var postData={dataString:true, CC:1}
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "tq/--record-events.inc.php",  data: postData });
```

this way jQuery will create the proper dataString parameter.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `POST` check to:

```
if(isset($_POST['CC'])) {
    clickCounter();
}
```

Also, if your `DIV` contains a link that navigates away from the page, clicking the link may cause the page location to change before the event bubbles down to the body tag. If so, you could try attaching an event to the link which calls `preventDefault` and therefore allow the event to bubble. If so, you could then detect that the user clicked the link and perform the navigation manually after recording the click. To show code as to how this can be achieved you need to post your full div code (including the link).

To add callbacks to the ajax call:

```
function ajax_post() {
    var dataString = 'CC='+1;  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tq/--record-events.inc.php", 
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: The links are dynamically generated by a JS script hosted on third party server. As of right now I am not clicking on a link in the div. I am just clicking the DIV. I see your point however.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `success` and `error` handler to the ajax call to see if it is encountering any problems?

Comment: No - I have not. How can I do that? Im just looking at JavaScript console in Firefox and it's not registering any errors.

Comment: Ajax calls won't throw javascript errors if they encounter a problem server-side. I'll update my answer with a suggestion on how to do it.

Comment: Server side isn't the problem because if `!isset` and reload the page -- a DB record is inserted successfully. (That eliminates server side error, doesn't it?)

Comment: I tried your updated code still no dice. Where is this `console_log` created? All I see is `error_log` and it's not helpful.